# get InputName of div element using js, no jquery please

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable that consists of an HTML tag as below:

```
let customDiv = '<div class="MuiAutocomplete-root" name="ApplyTo">Hello</div>';
```

I want to fetch the "name" which outputs --> **"ApplyTo"**... from the above customDiv variable. I don't want to use jquery. Wanted to implement it with vanilla javascript. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. (The first thing will be to parse the HTML.) ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: name is not a global attribute (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes ) .. you should use "data-name" for your site-specific properties to keep them HTML5 conform!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use string manipulation techniques like `Regex`:

```
customDiv.match('name="(.*?)"')[1]
```

Splitting or substrings:

```
customDiv.split('name="')[1].split('"')[0]
```

Or get a full on DOM going by using the `<template>` element.

```
let template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = customDiv;
let name = template.content.firstChild.getAttribute('name');
```